# Методы в Go. Классы в C++

Tags: c++, golang

Аналог методов в Go на С++ как реализовать?

```
type OutcomingDate struct {
    Time string
}

func (i *OutcomingDate) Packet(db *database.Database) (func(netes network.Netes), func(player *entitie.Player) []int) {...}

type IncomingAuth struct {
    Key           string
    Login         string
    Password      string
    MAC           string
    IsCheat       uint16
    ClientVersion uint16
}

func (i *IncomingAuth) Packet(db *database.Database) (func(netes network.Netes), func(player *entitie.Player) []int) {..}
```

Comment: То есть, как на с++ написать функцию, которая получает как аргументы две функции и возвращает структуру?

Comment: Может так? 
void Packet (..., i *OutcomingDate){}
 void Packet (..., i *IncomingAuth){}
А можно создать класс Packet и использовать шаблоны? Каким образом?

Comment: Поясните подробнее, что значит методы в Go - просто для C++'ников это темный лес... Можно своими словами - что вам нужно?

Comment: В синтаксисе скорее всего напутал, но смысл будет понятен.
Пример:
**func (i* string)packet{fmt.Print(i)/*Выводит code*/}
func (j* int)packet{{fmt.Print(j)/*Выводит size*/}
func main(){
str string = "432а"
size int = 100
str.packet
size.packet
}
Output: 432а 100**
А вообще мне нужно продумать архитектуру сервера, используя ООП. Написать класс Packet, чтобы отправлять пакеты (разной структуры). В примере, написаном первоначально, используются функции Packet, принимающие разные методы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я знаю Go, и совсем немного C++. Набросал нечто схожее с тем, что у вас:

```
#include <cinttypes>
#include <functional>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct MethodReturn {
    std::function<void (void)>             f1;
    std::function<std::vector<int> (void)> f2;
};

struct OutcomingDate {
    std::string time;

    struct MethodReturn Packet();
};

struct IncomingAuth {
    std::string key;
    std::string login;
    std::string password;
    std::string mac;
    uint16_t    is_cheat;
    uint16_t    client_version;
};

MethodReturn OutcomingDate::Packet() {
    auto f1 = []() {};
    auto f2 = []() -> std::vector<int> {
        std::vector<int> a;
        return a;
    };
    MethodReturn mr = {f1, f2};
    return mr;
}
```

Компилируется с `-std=c++11`. Если что-то неправильно, надеюсь люди, которые знают больше, напишут ответ получше.

Comment: Вы явно поскромничали про `знаю совсем немного C++` :D А зачем писать `struct` перед `MethodReturn`?

Comment: @gil9red Спасибо :) Думал, что без `struct` не скомпилируется, так как нет `typedef struct {/*...*/} MethodReturn`, но видимо ошибся. Убрал.

Comment: И без него соберется :) Можно убрать его и из OutcomingDate::Packet Меня немного смутило его наличие в объявлениях переменных и методах :)

Comment: Извините тупого в Go, но даже по вашему C++ коду я никак не пойму, в чем сверхзадача? Например, где играет `struct IncomingAuth`? Я вижу функцию, возвращающую структуру с двумя вызываемыми полями, но никак не соображу - зачем? Куда ее применить? Еще раз извините, но просто интересно...

Comment: @Harry Я просто переписал Go'шный код на C++. Так как в C++ нельзя вернуть несколько значений из функции, я положил их в структуру. Зачем так делать - спросите OP'а.

Comment: А, так суть просто в том, чтоб вернуть несколько значений?... Тогда понятно, спасибо.